# Mysql master slave replication

Tags: mysql, database, master-slave

While performing mysql replication i am observing below issue:

Pre requistes : I have three mysql databases all located on different machines. Lets suppose we have db1,db2,db3 and each of them have one table language. db1 is the master of db2. db2 is the slave of db1 and master of db3. db3 is the slave of db2

Scenario 1 while inserting something in language table of db1 changes are reflected to db2 in language tables but it doesnot propagate to db3 language table.

Expectation - since db3 is the slave of db2 then above change should reflect in db3 as well but its not happening

Scenario 2 but while inserting something in language table of db2 changes are reflected in language table of db3 perfectly.

I dont know whats the gap why insertion in db1 is propagating only to db2 and not db3

Please suggest if any configuration needs to be done

Comment: What is the difference between `db1` and `db2` that requires `db3` only be a slave for `db2`?

Comment: there is no difference still i want to replicate this

Comment: You mean there's no difference but you want it to be replicated as `db1 > db2 > db3` instead of `db1 > db2, db3`?

Comment: correct !  db2 to db3 is working but when inserted in db1 it updates db2 but not db3.

Comment: What would be the issue if you make both `db2` and `db3` as slave to `db1`? Maybe `db3` doesn't have any direct connection to `db1` (through LAN etc.)?

Comment: Not sure if it's relatable but here, try reading this:  https://code.google.com/archive/p/tungsten-replicator/wikis/TRCMultiMasterInstallation.wiki#Multi-Master_Installation . Also, you may get more responses for question like this at [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to turn on the [log_slave_updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates) flag.